# solr synonyms not being parsed

Tags: solr, synonym

I'm making an auto-suggest feature using past searches in solr. Synonyms.txt contains a list of common typos / misspellings etc. It's setup to run on index and using the anaysis tool in the admin I can see it's working correctly - however it doesn't seem to be applied to live data.

```
Field type :
<field name="suggest_ngrams" type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />

Schema:
<fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
     <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrement="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>   
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_en.txt" enablePositionIncrement="true"/>
 </analyzer>
```

```
and an example of synonyms.txt
watch, watches, watche, watchs => watch
```

So at index time I would expect "watche" to be replaced with "watch" - this doesn't seem to be the case (even though the analysis tool says that's what it's doing.

To be clear if I query solr (?q=watc) the phrase "watche" appears in the results

Any ideas or insight would be appreciated as I think everything is setup correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the issue right :-
The synonyms are used only during index time and do not affect the stored values.
So what you see in the analysis is the index time values, which seem to work fine.
When you query solr and it matches this result, the results would return "watche" only, as this is the original value stored.
The stored values are never modified and are stored as is and returned in the response.

Please clarify if i got it wrong.

Comment: Thats what Im not sure about - as I understand it the synonym filter should replace 'watche' with 'watch' when it does the index. So 'watche' shouldn't be in the index at all and shouldn't be returned in the results.

Comment: #Explicit mappings match any token sequence on the LHS of "=>"
#and replace with all alternatives on the RHS.  These types of mappings
#ignore the expand parameter in the schema.
#Examples:
i-pod, i pod => ipod,
sea biscuit, sea biscit => seabiscuit

Comment: So to me that reads that the term is replaced so shouldn't appear in the index....

Comment: The synonyms are only stored as indexed data and do not replace the stored data which is maintained differently and is returned with the response. So if you feed watche to solr, watch is the indexed data using in search and watche is the stored data returned with results.

Comment: Just added the synonym file to the query and still getting results back of "watche". How am I meant to filter this out?

Comment: As i said, you would always get watche (the stored value) in the results. The synonym at query would only change whats being searched upon. If you want watch to be return you need to do the handling before data is fed to solr. (Synonym logic @ client side)

Comment: Yep gotcha - worked on it over the weekend and as you said, the actual stored data doesnt change, just how you index/search for it. Thanks for your help Jayendra.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jayendra described solr doesn't change stored value. Therefore you should find another way of handling this obstacle. 
**In my case I come up with a solution using facet. If you facet on that field you receive the indexed value(Mapped).**

Another solution is You can apply the filters to the data in a separate process prior to loading the data into Solr